# Java: print list of students in each group

Tags: java

i had an array students[] contain students ' info. i want to write function studentsByGroup() which can list students in each group.

shry, i use sof the firsttime

my student class:

```
class Student {

//    private String
    private String name;
    private String id;
    private String group;
    private String email;

//    constructor #1
    public Student(String name, String id, String group, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.group = group;
        this.email = email;
    }

//    constructor #2
    public Student() {
        this.name = "Student";
        this.id = "000";
        this.group = "K61CB";
        this.email = "uet@vnu.edu.vn";
    }

//    constructor #3
    public Student(String n, String sid, String em) {
        this.name = n;
        this.id = sid;
        this.group = "K61CB";
        this.email = em;
    }

//    constructor #4
    public Student(Student s) {
        this.name = s.name;
        this.id = s.id;
        this.group = s.group;
        this.email = s.email;
    }

//     getter & setter

//    method
    public String getInfo() {
        return name + "\n" + id + "\n" + group + "\n" + email + "\n";
    }

}
```

how can i do with *studentsByGroup* and *removeStudent*

Comment: Please share with us the code you've written so far.

Comment: Show us what you've written so far.

Comment: Show us the `Student` class and the method that is to print students by group.

Comment: I am not sure why you are telling us your wishes, but OK, you have our blessing, feel free to write your code. Come back when you will face any *specific* problem.

Comment: Sure, go ahead and write it. You don't have to ask us for permission.

Comment: Some of the answers are being flip, but I think you need clarification on  how to use SO. In these forums, it is assumed you ran into a problem that you have tried to resolve for a long time, and reached a dead-end. Then, you would post your code with a clear and concise description of the problem. We help , then you upvote the helpful answers (This is common courtesy) and select the one that best resolves your problem.

Comment: Your student Array is of type `String`, if you want to save Students in this Array you should switch it to the type `Student`. Please also provide us with your implementation of the Student class so that we can help you.

Comment: i ediited students[] to Student students[] = new Student[100];

Comment: It should be `Student[] students = new Student[100]` - please also post your `Student` class so we know what we are working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a bit too complex if you just started with java. However if you research a bit about java-streams, this will became really strait-forward task :

```
Map<String, List<Student>> studentsByGroup = Arrays
                            .stream(students)
                            .collect(groupinBy(Student::getGroup));
```

This will give you a `map`, where `key` is Student's group, and `value` is a `list` which contains all students from current group.

The example of output might be something like

```
{ K61CB = [Student1,Student2], K63DE => [Student4] ....}
```

The same approach applies to remove operation. If let's say you want to remove student from you array/collection based on some property (`id == "000"` for example):

```
[array/collection].stream()
                  .filter(student => !student.getId().equals("000"))
                  .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

This will give you a list with students whose id is not equal to "000".

Of course you don't have to use streams here and simple foreach loop is enough.

[Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)

I hope this helps.